# nullPointerException in android prepopulated database program

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am tinkering around with a code that accesses a prepopulated database.  I am running into a nullPointerException error and I cant figure out whats going on.  I am going to post my code and if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

activity:

```
    public class Activity1c extends ListActivity {


IngredientHelper mDbHelper=null;
int char_property;
int char_name;
long a=1;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act1c);
    mDbHelper = new IngredientHelper(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    char_name = extras.getInt("char_name");
    char_property = extras.getInt("char_property");
    char_name+=1;
    char_property+=1;

    Toast.makeText(Activity1c.this,
            "The char_name you picked was " + char_name  + " and the property was "+char_property,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchNote(a);
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{IngredientHelper.COLUMN_TITLE,IngredientHelper.COLUMN_TITLE2};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.craft_type_display,R.id.spec_type_display};




    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.finalresult1, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);


}///end main




  }///end class
```

xml/act1c

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
```

xml/finalresult1

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/craft_type_display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spec_type_display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

class/IngredientHelper

```
public class IngredientHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 //we declare a bunch of useful constants
//the should be pretty obvious what they are!
private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data   /data/com.android.Database_Practice_3_31_12/databases/";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="infotest.sqlite";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "info";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE2 = "phone";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE3 = "fav_color";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE4 = "home_city";

public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;

private final Context myContext;

public IngredientHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    // check if exists and copy database from resource
    //createDB();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // check if exists and copy database from resource

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void createDatabase() {
    createDB();
}

private void createDB() {

    boolean dbExist = DBExists();

    if (!dbExist) {

        //By calling this method we create an empty database into the default system location
        //We need this so we can overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        //now we copy the database we included!
        copyDBFromResource();

    }

}    

private boolean DBExists() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try {
        String databasePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        db.setVersion(1);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Log.e("SqlHelper", "database not found");

    }

    if (db != null) {

        db.close();

    }

    return db != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDBFromResource() {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    try {

        inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file.");

    }

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    dbSqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (dbSqlite != null)
    {
        dbSqlite.close();
    }
    super.close();

}


public Cursor getCursor() {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

    String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_TITLE};

    //make sure you get your search by string pass correctly!
    Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    return mCursor;
}

public String getName(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(1));
}

public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

        dbSqlite.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                COLUMN_ID,  COLUMN_TITLE,COLUMN_TITLE2,COLUMN_TITLE3,COLUMN_TITLE4}, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

}

logcat

```
 04-04 19:54:50.764: E/AndroidRuntime(454): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.Database_Practice_3_31_12/com.android.Database_Practice_3_31_12.Activity1c}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.Database_Practice_3_31_12.IngredientHelper.fetchNote(IngredientHelper.java:173)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.Database_Practice_3_31_12.Activity1c.onCreate(Activity1c.java:49)
04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 04-04 19:54:50.774: E/AndroidRuntime(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Comment: I didnt open the database.....Thanks Yaqub!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ooof. Hard to follow all of this.

First, you're getting the error in fetchNote(). In the stack trace, the 5th line from the bottom shows this. You can use the line number at the end to get close to *where* it's happening.

My guess is that the query is failing.

My further guess is that it's because you're trying to "restore" a database by copying it byte-for-byte from someplace else. I'm not convinced that this will work. The best way to provide a prepopulated database in an app is to put its data in a flat file and then, when the app is first run, create the database and write the data into it.

In the Developers Guide, the source file DictionaryDatabase.java in the sample app SearchableDictionary gives example code for this.